# to retrieve attributes from an xml file by refereing that file in one xsl file

Tags: xslt

consider my 'destinationURLLookUp.xml' file has the following structure

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
               <destinationURLs xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
              <destinationURL name="Default Page" value="/abc/ab"/>
                     <destinationURL name="Home Page" value="/abc/ac"/>

                </destinationURLs>
```

I'm loading this file in my XSLT using the following XSLT code and have to retrieve the corresponding 'name' attribute for the 'value' that i'm processing for the

```
            <destinationURL>
```

tag.

XSLT snippet that i have tried

```
        <xsl:variable name="prop" select="document('destinationURLLookUp.xml')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="rep2" select="$prop/destinationURLs/destinationURL[@value=@url]/@name"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$rep2" />
```

where @url is the url value that i will get which matches the 'value' attibute of

```
               <destinationURL>
```

tag. I'm unable to get the output.Can i get the relative xpath for accessing 'name' attribute for the corrsponding 'value' matched.

tried with $prop/destinationURLs/destinationURL[@value=@url]/@name
shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just missing to explicitly specify the template current contenxt for the `@url` attribute. The correct XPath depends by the template where your instruction is placed.

I'm speaking about something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="rep2" 
 select="$prop/destinationURLs/destinationURL[@value=current()/@url]/@name"/>
```

Do note `current()/@url`.

Answer (score 1):

there is no attribute of url in your node, so @value=@url can never work.

If you have a URL you are using from your present row, put it in a variable first so

```
<xsl:variable name="url" select="@url"/>
<xsl:variable name="rep2" select="$prop/destinationURLs/destinationURL[@value=$url]/@name"/>
```

Comment: This is obviously working, because the correct context is implicitely used in the first assignment variable.